# CFPrint with URL variables

Tags: coldfusion, cfprint

I have a question about `<CFPrint>`.

I currently have a CFM page that I link to in my application which outputs a receipt to the screen. Users then print that web page and hand the receipt to the customer.

I would like to instead automatically print that CFM page so the user doesn't have to manually do it.

I though I could accomplish that with `<CFPrint>` but it doesn't seem to want to accept my source  with all my URL variables.

Here is what I tried:

```
 <cfprint 
                source = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\serviceticket\reports\dropoff_receipt.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticketID#&signature_id=#check_signature.id#" 

                printer = "\\EZServiceTrax\Dell">
```

But I receive an error that the source file doesn't exist. Can I accomplish what I want to do using this method? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, is there a better way?

Comment: Well, it's not saying that the method isn't working, it's saying the file doesn't exist. Check your source path!

Comment: The source is a *file path* not a URL. You're not making a request to a web server (wherein "URL parameters" would make sense; you're simply passing `<cfprint>` a file to print. From the server file system. You need to create the PDF file *first*, then send the finished doc to `<cfprint>`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a PDF using [CFDocument](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html) and then used variable as source to CFPrint? This is what the [CFPrint documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfprint.html) says about attribute 'source':

> **source** = "absolute or relative pathname to a PDF file|PDF document
>   variable"".... A PDF document variable in memory that is generated by the
>   cfdocument tag or the cfpdf tag.

Comment: But then I would have to save that cfdocument to disk first? How would you do that in the <cfdocument> tag?

Comment: No you won't. You can create a PDF document in memory; something like: <cfdocument format="PDF"  src="https://www.google.com/"  name="inMemoryPDFFile" /> and then use variable 'inMemoryPDFFile' as source to CFPrint.